# Flexbox div not taking the entire vertical space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having an issue with flexbox not filling spaces as I intend, I'm trying to see what I've been missing but couldn't wrap my head around it.
Below is a reproduction of my issue with a link to a codepen.
I need the div in the middle with `class="artcl-description"` to fill the remaining available space, taking into consideration the header and the footer and their content, I tried giving the parent (`class="artcl-content-container"`) properties `align-items: stretch; justify-content: stretch;` but no bueno, I don't want to resort to hard coded height values and percentages if that's possible :/

html:

```
<div class="artcl-container">
  <div class="artcl-content-container">
    <div class="artcl-title-container">
      <h1>Some Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="artcl-description">
      <p>Why is this not taking the remaining height?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="artcl-footer">
      <div>Some guy</div>
      <div>
        X/X/XXXX XX:XX:XX
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img class="artcl-thumbnail" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
</div>
```

scss:

```
$article-height: 240px;
$pad: 16px;

body {
  padding: 16px;
}

* {
  direction: ltr;
  margin: 0px;
}

.artcl-container {
  height: $article-height;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  .artcl-thumbnail {
    height: $article-height;
    width: $article-height;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .artcl-content-container {
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: stretch;
    .artcl-title-container {
      padding: $pad;
      border: dashed 1px wheat;
    }
    .artcl-description {
      flex: 1;
      padding: $pad;
      border: dashed 1px wheat;
    }
    .artcl-footer {
      padding: $pad;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      border: dashed 1px wheat;
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to Pen](https://codepen.io/darkystel/pen/PoGORVR)
[image: https://codepen.io/darkystel/pen/PoGORVR]

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/7v6KCT0

Comment: Your `div` with class `.artcl-container` already have `display: flex` rule. It will be correct if you apply the `display: inherit` for `.artcl-content-container` class. This way you will inherit the `flex` rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `display: flex;` to your class `.artcl-content-container`. I added it to your pen and it just works fine.

Comment: welp, I'm rolling on ground laughing right now.. I need a break lol